# Can't run pytesseract?

Tags: python, tesseract, python-imaging-library, python-tesseract

I'm trying to use pytesseract in a python script, but I keep getting the same error upon importing it. To check it was from pytesseract and not from something else, I typed `pytesseract` directly into my command line, and got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pytesseract", line 7, in <module>
from pytesseract.pytesseract import main
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pytesseract/__init__.py", line 
1, in <module>
from .pytesseract import (
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 9, in <module>
import Image
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 27, in <module>
from . import VERSION, PILLOW_VERSION, _plugins
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

But I know it's installed correctly, because when I try `pip install pytesseract --user`, I get back:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pytesseract in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pytesseract)
```

I also already have tesseract installed, which I know because typing `tesseract` into my command line gives me all its information. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Are you missing `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/__init__.py`? If so, try reinstalling Pillow: `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pillow`.

Comment: I ran `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pillow --user` successfully (only added the `--user` because otherwise I get a permission denied message), and `pytesseract` still does not wory (getting the same ValueError).

Comment: The problem is with `pillow`. How did you install it into the system `site-packages` before? Did you do `sudo pip install pillow`? Can you re-install it there?

Comment: Yes, I think I did do that before. Just now I ran `sudo pip install pillow`, and I'm just getting a `Requirement already satisfied` message.

Comment: You have `sudo pip` uninstall/reinstall it or upgrade it in place, like in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to install dependency packages of tesseract and import Image and Pillow packages
2. Or instead of pip install pytesseract, Download pytesseract package from online https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/ and install it